# Cauchy Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

If $C$ is the positively oriented unit circle |$z$| = 1, then is it true that

$\int_C\!Log(z+3)\, \mathrm{d}z$ = $0$

Why or why not?

Is is true because its analytic right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is only not analytic on $s:=${$Re(x)\leq3,y=0$}. Here you are using the principle branch of Log.

Comment: $ReLogz = log*\sqrt{x^2 + (iy)^2}$, How would we apply this for z+3?